# Grouping max(case) and (case)

Tags: sql, oracle

In situation where query would include

```
select
max(case when label in (value_1) then value else null) as "value_a"
   (case when label in (value_2) then value else null) as "value_b"
   (case when label in (value_3) then value else null) as "value_c"
   (case when label in (value_4) then value else null) as "value_d"
max(case when label in (value_5) then value else null) as "value_e"
from table;
```

how can group by be used to show results the way shown in file available in the [the link](https://files.fm/f/d5kk8866)?

Comment: You are missing all the commas between the selected terms and the `value_b`, `value_c` and `value_d` rows are not using an aggregation function so the query would raise a `Not a group by expression` exception. Also please provide a [MCVE] including sample data and your expected output (as your explanation is not clear what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your pseudo code query is supposed to do. It seems like you want to detect whether z = 'a', z= 'b', etc. exist in the table, but then why is it sometimes with `max` and sometimes without? What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want lists of values in each of the columns.  One way is to use `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by a desc) as seqnum_a,
             dense_rank() over (order by b desc) as seqnum_b,
             dense_rank() over (order by c desc) as seqnum_c,
             dense_rank() over (order by d desc) as seqnum_d,
             dense_rank() over (order by e desc) as seqnum_e
       from t
      )
select seqnum, max(a) as a, max(b) as b, max(c) as c, max(d) as d, max(e) as e
from ((select distinct seqnum_a as seqnum, a, NULL as b, NULL as c, NULL as d, NULL as e
       from t
      ) union all
      (select distinct seqnum_b, NULL, b, NULL as c, NULL as d, NULL as e
       from t
      ) union all
      (select distinct seqnum_c, NULL, NULL as b, c, NULL as d, NULL as e
       from t
      ) union all
      (select distinct seqnum_d, NULL, NULL as b, NULL as c, d, NULL as e
       from t
      ) union all
      (select distinct seqnum_e, NULL as a, NULL as b, NULL as c, NULL as d, e
       from t
      )
     ) abcde
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```